# Click button with selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate my homework on a website called edgenuity.com. I have made it so i can login and get to my courses but i can not click the next activity button of this website. I have been able to click other buttons with selenium but not this one.

here is my code:

```
import unittest
import edgenuitySolver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import tracemalloc
import time
tracemalloc.start()


def validateLogin(username, password):
    print("username entered :", username.get())
    print("password entered :", password.get())
    print("course entered :", course.get())

#window
tkWindow = Tk()  
tkWindow.geometry('400x150')  
tkWindow.title('Edgenuity Login Form')

#username label and text entry box
usernameLabel = Label(tkWindow, text="User Name").grid(row=0, column=0)
username = StringVar()
usernameEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=username).grid(row=0, column=1)  

#password label and password entry box
passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)  
password = StringVar()
passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)  

#amount of courses available
courseLable = Label(tkWindow, text="Number of courses?").grid(row=2, column=0)
course = IntVar()
courseEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=course).grid(row=2, column=1)  

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, username, password)

#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Save Info", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=0)  

tkWindow.mainloop()



class edegnuityBot(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://auth.edgenuity.com/Login/Login/Student")
        self.assertIn("Edgenuity", driver.title)
        
        driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
        driver.implicitly_wait(5) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
        try:
            print("finding element...")
            element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="LoginPassword"]')
            element.send_keys(password.get())
            print("found element and sent")
            element2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="LoginUsername"]')
            element2.send_keys(username.get())
            time.sleep(2.5)
            loginButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="LoginSubmit"]')
            loginButton.click()
            time.sleep(5)
        finally:
            print("all good")
#active session
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        try:
            countinueButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnContinue"]')
            countinueButton.click()
            time.sleep(2.5)
        except:
            print("everything goods")
        else:
            print("no active sessions")
#next activity
```

here is the code for the website

```
<a href="/" target="_self" class="btn-primary enrollment-card-btn-next btn d-flex align-items-baseline" title="Next Activity">Next Activity</a>
```

Comment: `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Next Activity']"` Have you tried this?

Comment: @AnandGautam Thanks for the help but it didnt work sadly. I think that the reason its not working is because the button im trying to click is in another window or frame.

Comment: @AnandGautam i got it to work!! all i did was get rid of the class and the functions, then it magically worked!! Thanks for the help still, much appreciated